# Is "embed" a reserved word in the context of package management?

Tags: go, module

I am doing some simple test, and happend to name my package "embed", i.e. the first line of my `go.mod` is `module embed`. Then, when doing `go mod tidy`, it complains:

```
go: warning: "all" matched no packages
```

and when doing `go build .` no error reported, and the executable is **not** generated.

After searching for the error message and didn't get relevant answer, I renamed the package to 'test': `module test`, then everythin is fine.

I'm using Go 1.17

Comment: [`embed`](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) is a package in the standard library.

Comment: You must name a module like "my.module". It must contain a dot.

Comment: @Volker this is **not** true.   I have used module name without dot many many times. Maybe it is required if you write a "library"??

Comment: @xrfang You are right. There is absolutely no need to use a dot in your module name. Except when it collides with a stdlib name, you want to publish it, etc. pp. I'm sorry that I formulated a sensible advice and best practice as "must". Please excuse.